# How to serve hugo in a specifc domain?

Tags: local, hugo, static-site, laragon

I installed Hugo on laragon in local. I put it in a path localhost/hugosite.
When i run "hugo serve" the site is visible in localhost:1313 but i want to show it in "localhost/hugosite". How can i do that? I tried changing the base url in config but nothing seems happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the default HTTP port (80) via `-p` option.

```
$ hugo server -b http://localhost/hugosite -p 80
```